# MDX result set group by a custom name

Tags: ssas, mdx

Here I came up with a scenario while developing a report, I need to group the result set first with a custom name and then year.

> WITH MEMBER [measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount] 
>   AS
>   ( 
>   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], 
>   PARALLELPERIOD
>   ([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year], 1, [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember) 
>   ),FORMAT_STRING = "Currency"
>
> MEMBER [measures].[Varience]  AS
>   (
>   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] - [measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount]
>   )
>   MEMBER [Measures].[PercentageVarience] AS
>   (
>   CASE WHEN [measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount] IS NULL OR ISEMPTY([measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount]) THEN 1
>        WHEN [measures].[Internet Sales Amount] IS NULL THEN -100 
>   ELSE [measures].[Varience] 
>    /
>   [measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount] 
>   END )
>   ,FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"
>   MEMBER [measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count] 
>   AS
>   ( 
>   [Measures].[Internet Order Count], 
>   PARALLELPERIOD
>   ([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year], 1, [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember) 
>   )
>
> MEMBER [measures].[Order Count Varience]  AS
>   (
>   [Measures].[Internet Order Count] - [measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count]
>   )
>   MEMBER [Measures].[Order Count PercentageVarience] AS
>   (
>   CASE WHEN [measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count] IS NULL OR ISEMPTY([measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count]) THEN 1
>        WHEN [measures].[Internet Order Count] IS NULL THEN -1 
>   ELSE [measures].[Order Count Varience] 
>    /
>   [measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count] 
>   END )
>   ,FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"
>
> SELECT {[measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
>   , [measures].[Varience],[Measures].[PercentageVarience]
>   , [measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count],[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
>   , [measures].[Order Count Varience],[Measures].[Order Count PercentageVarience]} ON COLUMNS
>   , [Date].[Calendar Year].children ON ROWS
>   FROM [Adventure Works]

The result set for the first 4 columns needs to come as [Internet Sales] and next 4 columns as [Internet Orders] so in report layer I get the group by options with custom names.
Expected output from the MDX as
[image]
Could you plea help me to find a way to add a group column to result set

Comment: you should improve the formatting....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fake [mdx calculated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Calculated%20Members.html) on another dimension to get your label. In our example let's use the [Organization] dimension for this :

```
WITH 
  // Does not change the value of a tuple
  MEMBER [Organization].[Organizations].[Internet Sales] as [Organization].[Organizations].defaultmember 
  MEMBER [Organization].[Organizations].[Internet Order] as [Organization].[Organizations].defaultmember
SELET
  {[Organization].[Organizations].[Internet Sales]} * {[measures].[Previous Year Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] , [measures].[Varience],[Measures].[PercentageVarience]}
  +
  {[Organization].[Organizations].[Internet Order]} * {[measures].[Previous Year Internet Order Count],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] , [measures].[Order Count Varience],[Measures].[Order Count PercentageVarience]} 
  ON 0,
... as your request
```

That should get your result

Comment: Awesome, I know MDX can do anything once we have data in the cube. A big thank you